# Strange black Shadow cast by WPF UI after switching back from a different user on desktop

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have an application designed in WPF. I can run the application and minimize it to switch to a different user on desktop. But when I come back to the same user and try to launch the minimized application, it casts a strange black shadow.

This is the only scenario where I have noticed this odd behavior. In general, the `ActualWidth` and `Width` of the window are the same, but in this scenario I see a drastic difference as `ActualWidth` includes some garbage value. I am using data grid in the application.

#### Scenario:

1. Launch the application and minimize it.
2. Log in to a different user and log out.
3. Switch back to the original user and launch the minimized application.
4. A strange black shadow is being cast on the bottom and right side of the application.

[image: Attached image]